# What are the qualifications needed for dressage judges?

Tags: rules, dressage

At the international highest level of dressage (Grand Prix), what are the qualifications a judge has to have in order to qualify as a judge?

Comment: I'm afraid there were no tags for any equestrian sport (that I could find) other than horse-racing. A generic equestrian or dressage tag would be great.

Comment: [tag:dressage] created :-)